# Need help decoding JSON from Riot API with PHP

Tags: php, json, riot-games-api

As a part of an assignment I am trying to pull some statistics from the Riot API (JSON data for League of Legends). So far I have managed to find summoner id (user id) based on summoner name, and I have filtered out the id's of said summoner's previous (20) games. However now I can't figure out how to get the right values from the JSON data. So this is when I'll show you my code I guess:

$matchIDs is an array of 20 integers (game IDs)

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 1; $i++)
{
$this_match_data = get_match($matchIDs[$i], $server, $api);
$processed_data = json_decode($this_match_data, true);
var_dump($processed_data);
}
```

As shown above my for loop is set to one, as I'm just focusing on figuring out one before continuing with all 20. The above example is how I got the match IDs and the summoner IDs. I'll add those codes here for comparison:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 19; $i++)
{
$temp = $data['matches'][$i]['matchId'];
$matchIDs[$i] = json_decode($temp, true);
}
```

$data is the variable I get when I pull all the info from the JSON page, it's the same method I use to get $this_match_data in the first code block.

```
function match_list($summoner_id, $server, $api)    
{
$summoner_enc = rawurlencode($summoner);
$summoner_lower = strtolower($summoner_enc);
$curl =curl_init('https://'.$server.'.api.pvp.net/api/lol/'.$server.'/v2.2/matchlist/by-summoner/'.$summoner_id.'?api_key='.$api.'');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return $result;
}
```

Now to the root of the problem, [This is where](http://thooom.win/match2676989546.json) I put the data I get from the site, so you can see what I am working with. Now by using the following code I can get the first value in that file, the match ID.

```
echo $processed_data['matchId'];
```

But I can't seem to lock down any other information from this .json file. I've tried typing stuff like ['region'] instead of ['matchId'] with no luck as well as inserting index numbers like $processed_data[0], but nothing happens. This is just how I get the right info from the first examples and I am really lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I think I've figured it out myself. By adding this to the code I can print out the json file in a way more human-friendly way, and that should make it much easier to handle the data.

```
echo ("<pre>");
var_dump($processed_data);
echo ("</pre>");
```

Comment: Personally I prefer `print_r($processed_data);` for readability, or even `var_export($processed_data);`